# Импортирование перменной из __name__ == __main__

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, python-import

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create engine
    engine = CarEngine()
```

Есть такой код, так вот когда пытаюсь импортировать из этого файла переменную engine -

> from file import engine

Ввыдается ошибка что cannot import name engine, вопрос - как правильно импортировать из name == main?

Comment: from file import CarEngine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная `__name__` равна `__main__` только в точке входа в программу - в скрипте переданном интерпретатору при запуске. В импортируемых скриптах эта переменная `__main__` не равна, поэтому блок `if` не будет выполнен и переменная `engine` не будет определена.

[Соответствующий раздел документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html).